Any solution to play Roblox on Linux?
Has anyone figured out how to play Roblox on Linux? I’m looking for solutions and would love to hear your experiences or advice. Any help is welcome.

Per the Roblox Fandom page on Linux compatibility:

While Roblox does not officially support Linux, the Wine compatibility layer for running Windows programs is able to run Roblox Player and Roblox Studio on Linux.

Support has been removed, re-enabled, and removed again (February 28th 2024) by Roblox Corporation.
However,

Roblox can still be played through Waydroid on Linux, but support for games will be limited to ones that support mobile. This also comes with the catch that Nvidia GPU users are currently limited to software rendering only in Waydroid, and for acceptable performance AMD GPU users have to use a custom libndk patch made by Slappy826 to be able to play with libndk for acceptable performance, Intel iGPU users should have an acceptable experience with libhoudini.


From what I understand, you can 'play' Roblox on Waydroid, but I get the message 'Roblox is not compatible with my system.' Is it just a patch to play, right? (according to what I understood, I emphasize that I don't know much about these patches)

Mmm, but Waydroid is blocking the systems (according to what I've researched); what is Slappy826's patch used for? Once I have it downloaded (installed), what do I do?

@YourLocalRobloxian Did you read and follow the instructions on the GitHub page? It says this libndk_fixer "fixes the roblox app crashing inside Waydroid when using libndk_translation." As for your former question: Waydroid is an emulator, a container program that emulates an Android environment on a Linux-based OS.

Ah, thank you very much, I think I already found the solution.
